# N88BASIC エミュレーターでコードを実行しても、応答なしで終了しない

Tags: basic

N88BASIC  エミュレーターで下記のコードを実行したのですが、
実行したまま応答せずに終了しませんでした。

エラーがあるとエラー行を警告してくれるエミュレーターですが、
警告はありませんでした。

自己解決出来ずに投稿しました。
ご知見を頂けますと幸いです。

```
10 DEFINT I-N
20 DIM F(4,4), G(4,4), D(4,4), E(4,4), FF(4,4), DD(4,4)
22 DIM T(5), H(5), X(5), Y(5), P(5), Q(5), B(5), W(5), A(8,100), AA(100)
30 DEF FNR(I,J)=F(I,3)*F(J,4)-F(I,4)*F(J,3)
32 DEF FNRD(I,J)=D(I,3)*F(J,4)+F(I,3)*D(J,4)-D(I,4)*F(J,3)-F(I,4)*D(J,3)
50 READ NL: N=NL+1:LPRINT :LPRINT "WALL CONSTRUCTION"
52 LPRINT " LAYER TH   LAMDA   LAMDA'  A          A'        B       W"
60 FOR L=0 TO N
62 READ TH,CT,CH:LPRINT USING " ##  #.### ##.#### ##.#####";L,TH,CT,CH;
64 IF TH=0 THEN T(L)=1/CT:  H(L)=1/CH: P(L)=0.5: Q(L)=0.5:LPRINT: GOTO 80
66 READ DT,DH,B,W:LPRINT USING "##.####^^^^";DT,DH,B,W
68 T(L)=TH/CT: H(L)=TH/CH: Z=SQR((DT-DH)^2+4*DT*DH*B*W)
70 X(L)=TH^2*(DT+DH-Z)/(2*DT*DH): Y(L)=TH^2*(DT+DH+Z)/(2*DT*DH)
72 P(L)=(1+(DT-DH)/Z)/2: Q(L)=(1-(DT-DH)/Z)/2: B(L)=DH*B/Z: W(L)=DT*W/Z
80 NEXT 
100 LPRINT :LPRINT "Step Responses in Exponential Series"
102 LPRINT "  Teram   EXPNT";:FOR M=1 TO 4:LPRINT "    COEF";M;:NEXT
104 LPRINT:LPRINT SPC(14);:FOR M=5 TO 8:LPRINT "    COEF";M;:NEXT
110 K=0: S=0: GOSUB 200: R=FNR(1,2): GOTO 160
120 GOSUB 200: R=FNR(1,2): RD=FNRD(1,2): Z=0: ZZ=0: IF K=1 THEN 140
130 FOR I=1 TO K-1: Z=Z+A(0,I)/(S+AA(I)): ZZ=ZZ+A(0,I)/(S+AA(I))^2: NEXT 
140 SS=S-(1/R-Z)/(RD/R^2-ZZ):PRINT "     ";SS
150 IF S>SS THEN S=SS: GOTO 120 ElSE R=S*RD: AA(K)=-S: A(0, K)=1/RD
160 A(1,K)=F(2,4)/R: A(2,K)=-F(2,3)/R: A(3,K)=FNR(3,2)/R: A(4,K)=FNR(4,2)/R
162 A(5,K)=-F(1,4)/R: A(6,K)=F(1,3)/R: A(7,K)=FNR(1,3)/R: A(8,K)=FNR(1,4)/R
170 LPRINT:LPRINT USING "#### ##.####^^^^";K,AA(K);: FOR M=1 TO 4
172 LPRINT USING " ##.####^^^^";A(M,K);: NEXT:LPRINT:LPRINT SPC(16);
174 FOR M=5 TO 8:LPRINT USING " ##.####^^^^";A(M,K);: NEXT:LPRINT
180 IF K<101 AND S>-10 THEN K=K+1: S=0: GOTO 120
182 END
200 FOR I=1 TO 4: FOR J=1 TO 4: F(I,J)=0: D(I,J)=0: NEXT: F(I,I)=1: NEXT
210 FOR L=0 TO N: T=T(L): H=H(L): P=P(L): Q=Q(L): B=B(L): W=W(L): X=X(L): Y=Y(L)
220 IF S*X=0 THEN 240
230 U=SQR(-S*X): X1=COS(U): X2=SIN(U)/U: X3=-U*SIN(U)
232 X4=X*X2/2: X5=-X*(X1-X2)/(2*U^2): X6=X*(X1+X2)/2
234 V=SQR(-S*Y): Y1=COS(V): Y2=SIN(V)/V: Y3=-V*SIN(V)
236 Y4=Y*Y2/2: Y5=-Y*(Y1-Y2)/(2*V^2): Y6=Y*(Y1+Y2)/2: GOTO 250
240 X1=1: X2=1: X3=0: X4=X/2: X5=X/6: X6=X: Y1=1: Y2=1: Y3=0: Y4=Y/2: Y5=Y/6: Y6=Y
250 G(1,1)=P*X1+Q*Y1: G(1,2)=B*(X1-Y1): G(1,3)=T*(P*X2+Q*Y2): G(1,4)=H*B*(X2-Y2)
252 G(2,1)=W*(X1-Y1): G(2,2)=Q*X1+P*Y1: G(2,3)=T*W*(X2-Y2): G(2,4)=H*(Q*X2+P*Y2)
254 G(3,1)=(P*X3+Q*Y3)/T: G(3,2)=B*(X3-Y3)/T: G(3,3)=G(1,1): G(3,4)=G(1,2)*H/T
256 G(4,1)=W*(X3-Y3)/H: G(4,2)=(Q*X3+P*Y3)/H: G(4,3)=G(2,1)*T/H: G(4,4)=G(2,2)
258 E(1,1)=P*X4+Q*Y4: E(1,2)=B*(X4-Y4): E(1,3)=T*(P*X5+Q*Y5): E(1,4)=H*B*(X5-Y5)
260 E(2,1)=W*(X4-Y4): E(2,2)=Q*X4+P*Y4: E(2,3)=T*W*(X5-Y5): E(2,4)=H*(Q*X5+P*Y5)
262 E(3,1)=(P*X6+Q*Y6)/T: E(3,2)=B*(X6-Y6)/T: E(3,3)=E(1,1): E(3,4)=E(1,2)*H/T
264 E(4,1)=W*(X6-Y6)/H: E(4,2)=(Q*X6+P*Y6)/H: E(4,3)=E(2,1)*T/H: E(4,4)=E(2,2)
270 FOR I=1 TO 4: FOR J=1 TO 4: FF(I,J)=F(I,J): DD(I,J)=D(I,J): NEXT: NEXT
272 FOR I=1 TO 4: FOR J=1 TO 4: F=0: D=0: FOR M=1 TO 4
274 F=F+FF(I,M)*G(M,J): D=D+DD(I,M)*G(M,J)+FF(I,M)*E(M,J): NEXT
276 F(I,J)=F: D(I,J)=D: NEXT: NEXT
280 NEXT :RETURN
500 DATA 2                      
510 DATA 0, 8,  38              
520 DATA 0.01, 0.5, 0.004, 2.2936E-04, 6.8966E-07, 1596.3, 5.5172E-04
530 DATA 0.1, 1.25, 0.00168, 8.3949E-04, 4.9499E-07, 1367.6, 4.8615E-04
540 DATA 0, 20, 95
```

Comment: 「エラーがあれば教えてくれるはず」とありますが、恐らく文法的なエラーなどに対しての話だと思うので、無限ループのようなミスは自分で見つける必要があると思います。

Comment: 無限ループの視点から改善をしてみたいと思います。

Comment: このような場合、あちこちにPRINT分を入れて、その行を通ったら画面上にメッセージを出すようにすると、問題解決の助けになると思います。

Comment: DATA文の末尾に空白があり、入力待ちの状態だったことが原因だと分かりました。また、LPRINT文は認識してくれないようで、ご指摘のとおりPRINT文にしたところ問題解決できました。無事に計算実行できました。

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄で終わらせず、ぜひ **個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。(自己回答も歓迎されます)

Comment: エミュレータというのが具体的に何であるかわかる名称を提示するのが好ましいと思います。 オリジナルと違う部分が問題であるような事例だと思うので。

Comment: エミュレータは「N88互換BASIC for Windows95」でした。Vectorから利用させて頂きました。